# Viewport iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, viewport

Hello I am currently trying to make an iframe which has the width and height of the viewport.
Here is the code:

```
document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML="<iframe id='myframe' src='index.html' width=&#39;" + viewportwidth +"&#39; height=&#39;" +viewportheight +"&#39;></iframe>"
```

Nothing shows up when I run it. (& #39; is ')

If you have a better way of doing this, that would be helpful as well.

The reason I am trying to do this is because I am running two jquery extensions, and they conflict with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Using the special character `&#96;` is most likely messing up your code. Just use an escaped quote instead by replacing `&#96` with `\"`. When writing HTML with javascript it's often easier to put the HTML string in single quotes, rather than double quotes, so you can write the HTML as your normally would, without having to escape the quotes.

Comment: I'm sorry but that didn't work, here is the new code.    document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML="<iframe id='myframe' src='index.html' width=\'" + viewportwidth+"+px\' height=\'"+viewportheight+"+px\'></iframe>"

Comment: You just need to pay attention to your single and double quotes. It should be like this: `document.getElementById("myframe").innerHTML="<iframe id='frame2' src='index.html' width='" + viewportwidth + "px' height='" + viewportheight + "px'></iframe>";` Notice I switched the id to `frame2`. You should never have two elements on a page with the same id.